# install ffmpeg on 1and1 dedicated server

Tags: ffmpeg

anyone know how to do this? have contacted the server company who will not help

I have a dedicated server, running on centos parralells plesk panel

thanks

Comment: Did you even try googling? Very first result for "ffmpeg centos" was http://www.tuxmachines.org/node/17063 "How to install ffmpeg on centos/rhel".

Comment: yes tried googling, read through and tried 10-12 different thigs and none have worked

Answer (score 2):

I found this to be the best guide when installing ffmpeg.

http://www.videochat-scripts.com/install-ffmpeg-mplayer-flvtool2-yamdi-x264-theora-mp3lame-vorbis-ogg-faac/

Make sure you follow each step. If the install of any dependency fails, retry.

Good luck.

**EDIT**

The guide doesn't include qt-faststart. Follow this if you need it:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg
make tools/qt-faststart
sudo checkinstall --pkgname=qt-faststart --pkgversion="$(./version.sh)" --backup=no \
    --deldoc=yes --fstrans=no --default install -D -m755 tools/qt-faststart \
    /usr/local/bin/qt-faststart
```

Also, follow @pablo's point about git rather than svn.

Comment: this is pretty accurate except install ffmpeg from git rather than svn.

Comment: @pablo - Agreed, good point.

Comment: @pablo - Great link below. Wish I found this a long time ago - would have made my life a lot easier!

Answer (score 2):

Hi I hope this helps you, it seems pretty popular for easy installs.

http://www.ffmpeginstaller.com/

> ffmpeginstaller is a free software
>   completely written in bash shell
>   script. The purpose of this script is
>   to build a video streaming platform
>   form in your Gnu/Linux server. So you
>   can start video streaming  websites
>   and avoid the cost of installations. 
>   This script not only install ffmpeg
>   but also all its friends packages.